# Convert UTF-16 numbers to UTF-8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, utf-16

I have a iPad app where the user enters a phone number in a text field.  Sometimes the phone number is entered in UTF-16 (Japanese *sometimes* enter their phone numbers this way), but most of the time in UTF-8.

My question is three-part:

- is there a way I can tell if the number is UTF-8 or UTF-16?
- how do I convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8, given the number is numeric?
- having looked and found nothing, anyone know of a good treatise on this subject? (converting back and forth in iOS).

Comment: If the user is entering the number into a `UITextField`, then you have an `NSString`. How does the user enter this string in different encodings? That doesn't make any sense. You can convert the `NSString` to `NSData` using whatever encoding you want, but the user has no control over the encoding during entry into a text field.

Comment: What do you mean with "a number is entered in UTF-16 or UTF-8"?

Comment: @MartinR: UTF-16 encoded bytestreams use at least 2 bytes per codepoint, whereas UTF-8 can go as low as one byte per codepoint.

Comment: @datenwolf: I know UTF-8 and UTF-16, but I do not see how that applies to text fields, which use `NSString` (as also noted by rmaddy in his comment).

Comment: I understand the difference... I was just told this by the person who is delivering the specs for the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Unicode encodings can be converted between without problem. UTF-8 is just another encoding for the same thing as UTF-16. The main reason that East Asian users use UTF-16 more often than UTF-8 is, that it's more space efficient to encode codepoints of the East Asian Unicode planes in UTF-16.

Coversion between Unicode encodings is more or less straightforward: Unicode assigns each character a codepoint. Codepoints are encoded into bytestreams in a encoding specific way. So what you must do is decode the UTF-16 bytestream into single Unicode codepoints and then backconvert them into a UTF-8 encoded bytestream.

> is there a way I can tell if the number is UTF-8 or UTF-16?

That's not what you're looking for. You want to know the encoding of the character string.

> how do I convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8

Preferrably using a tested Unicode library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). Also [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) may be usefull to you, but mind the license.

Comment: I believe `libiconv` is installed by default on iOS, at least there's an iconv.dylib file in the sysroot of the toolchain. Also, can't `NSString` itself handle conversions, as I described?

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way I can tell if the number is UTF-8 or UTF-16?

No. `NSString` doesn't expose this implementation detail. And you **should not** need it. (If you do, that's a design error, most probably.)

> how do I convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8, given the number is numeric?

(Numbers **are** numeric, or am I missing something?) Well, you can use `NSString` as a kind of "bridge" to convert between C strings (character arrays) of different encodings:

```
unichar utf16_string[] = // some UTF-16 C string
NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:utf16_string
   length:sizeof(utf16_string) / sizeof(utf16_string[0])
   encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding
];
const char *utf8_string = [tmp UTF8String];
```

> having looked and found nothing, anyone know of a good treatise on this subject?

[NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)